# Lines of Code limit in VB6

Tags: vb6

We have a legacy VB6 application that is very procedural.  This thing is gigantic!

My boss thinks that there is a 65000 lines of code limit in the editor of VB6 however, I could not find any reference to that.

Does anyone know if there is in fact a limit to the lines of code in the VB6 editor?

Comment: None that I've ever heard of.

Comment: I would hope in 1998-2000 Microsoft wouldn't have made the limit so small.  How many lines do you feel it is?  There are QA tools that will count the number of lines of code in a file.

Comment: If there is a limit, it would be for a particular file, not for the whole project. I have vb6 projects with many 100's of thousands of lines of code. Even if you *could* put 65k+ in a single file, it wouldn't be a very good idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess he is referring to this:

[Code Limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240819%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)

> The amount of code that can be loaded into a form, class, or standard module is limited to 65,534 lines.

More limitations if you follow the link.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is one for .Net?  BTW - I'm not arguing for doing this in .Net...  Just getting knowledge.

Comment: @Jeff http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdzat713(v=VS.100).aspx can't find limitations on lines per file, only on characters per line